# I am Unable create a Community User .Here is my Code:

Tags: apex, community

```
/**
 * An apex page controller that supports self registration of users in communities that allow self registration
 */

public with sharing class CommunitiesSelfRegController {

    public String firstName {get; set;}
    public String lastName {get; set;}
    public String email {get; set;}
    public String password {get; set {password = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String confirmPassword {get; set { confirmPassword = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }
    public String communityNickname {get; set { communityNickname = value == null ? value : value.trim(); } }

    public CommunitiesSelfRegController() {}

    private boolean isValidPassword() {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    public PageReference registerUser() {

           // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
        if (!isValidPassword()) {
            ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
            ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
            return null;
        }    

        String profileId = '00e28000000MTPv'; // To be filled in by customer.
      //  String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
        String accountId = '00328000004NUd4'; // To be filled in by customer.


        /*Account acc = new Account(Name = 'CompanyName');
        //acc.ownerId = ownerId;
        insert acc;
        system.debug('::::acc:::::::::::::'+acc);
        accountId = acc.id;*/

       // contactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('conatctid');

        // Contact c = [Select c.LastName, c.Phone, c.OwnerId From Contact c WHERE id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];



                String userName = email;
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = userName;
        u.Email = email;
        u.FirstName = firstName;
        u.LastName = lastName;
        u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
        u.ProfileId = profileId;
        System.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+u);
        insert u;
         System.debug('111111111111'+u);
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);

       if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                return Site.login(userName, password, ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startURL'));
            }
            else {
                PageReference page = System.Page.CommunitiesSelfRegConfirm;
                page.setRedirect(true);
                return page;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply add the ContactID to the User you are creating

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a community / portal user you need to have the ContactID specified when inserting the User record:

```
Account a = New Account(Name = 'TestDistributorAccount');
insert a;

Contact c = New Contact(FirstName = 'Distributor', LastName = 'Test', AccountID = a.id);
insert c;

user u = New User(
    UserName = 'test_' + math.random() + '@test.com',
    FirstName = 'Test-First',
    LastName = 'Test-Last',
    Alias = 'test',
    email = 'test' + math.random() + '@abbott.com',
    CommunityNickName = string.valueOf(math.random()).substring(0,6),
    ProfileID = p.id,
    TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/New_York', 
    LocaleSidKey = 'en_US', 
    EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
    LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
    ContactID = c.id

    );

insert u;
```

Replacing the random values as necessary (Code is from a test method)

Comment: Can i make contact dynamic ...while creating..because if i hardcode contact name .. every contact will be created with the mentioned name..please provide me the solution.